# How can I read more than one sector with BIOS calls?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, bootloader, bios

I have a bootsector which is meant to load a file called BOOT.BIN from a floppy disk image. However I can not figure out how to read more than one sector from the file.
The FAT 12 is at 0x10000.
The BOOT.BIN file will be put at 0x40000.
The code:

```
foundfile:
        mov word ax,[es:di+0x0f]
        push ax ;save file cluster
        ;now to parse the fat
        mov dx,second_boot_segment
        mov es,dx
        xor bx,bx
        
        read_file_sector:
            pop ax ;retrieve file cluster
            mov byte dl,[drive_num]
            mov cx,ax
            add cx,31
            push ax ;save cluster number
            mov al,1
            call readdisk
            pop ax ;retrieve cluster number
            
        find_clusters:
            push es
            push bx
            mov cx,fat_segment
            mov es,cx
            xor bx,bx
            xor dx,dx
            mov cx,3
            mul cx
            shr ax,1
            ;ax is now (clusternum*3)/2
            test ax,1
            
            jz short evennum
            
            oddnum:
                shr ax,4
                jmp short find_clusters_continued
                
            evennum:
                and ax,0x0fff
                
            find_clusters_continued:
                cmp ax,0x0ff0
                jae short finishedread ;read all of file
                
                mov word ax,[es:bx]
                
                pop bx
                pop es
                
                push ax
                
                add bx,512 ;next sector
                jmp short read_file_sector
                
        finishedread:
            jmp second_boot_segment:0000
            jmp fatalerror
```

========================================================================
readdisk and other functions:

````
readdisk: ;input: es:bx for where disk data is stored, al for sectors, cx for lba, drive_num for drive output: carry flag on error, ah is return type, al is the number of sectors read
        push dx ;save dx
        call lbatochs
        mov byte dl,[drive_num]
        mov ah,2
        int 13h
        jc short resetdisk
        mov byte dl,[drive_num]
        pop dx ;restore dx
        ret
        
        resetdisk:
            push ax
            mov ah,0
            int 13h
            jc short fatalerror
            pop ax
            jmp short readdisk

    fatalerror:
        mov ax,0x0003 ;ah = 0 al = 3
        int 10h
        
        mov si,boot_error
        mov ax,0xb800
        mov es,ax
        xor bx,bx
        cld
        
        printloop:
            lodsb
            or al,al ;is the last character read
            jz short infloop
            mov ah,0x0f ;color
            mov word [es:bx],ax ;write to vram
            add bl,2 ;as long a the text is less than 256 bytes this works
            jmp short printloop
    
    lbatochs: ;input: cx for lba, output: cx for cylinder and sector, and dh for head
        push ax ;save for later
        push bx ;save bx
        
        ;find temp variable
        xor dx,dx
        mov ax,cx ;ax now has lba
        push ax ;save lba
        mov word bx,[sects_per_track] ;sectors per track
        div bx ;ax is now temp
        
        ;cylinder
        push ax ;save temp
        xor dx,dx
        mov word bx,[num_heads] ;number of heads
        div bx ;ax is now cylinder
        mov cx,ax ;cx stores cylinder
        pop ax ;retrieve temp
        ;cx is now cylinder
        
        ;head
        push dx ;heads already in dx
        
        ;sector
        pop dx ;pop dx to get stack value underneath it
        pop ax ;retrieve lba
        push dx ;push dx back on
        push cx ;save cylinder
        xor dx,dx
        mov word bx,[sects_per_track]
        div bx
        inc dx ;dx now has sectors
        mov bx,dx ;now bx has sectors
        pop cx
        pop dx
        
        ;put params together
        mov ch,cl ;cylinder in ch
        mov cl,bl ;sector in cl
        mov dh,dl ;head in dh
        mov dl,0 ;erase dl
        
        pop bx ;load old bx
        pop ax ;load old ax
        ret
``` This read disk code likely is not causing the issues as I have loaded many other sectors with this.
````

Comment: What part is causing you problem? If you can read one sector, you can read any number of sectors just use a loop and adjust the disk and memory addresses as appropriate.

Comment: i will try that Edit: It does make it loop but it will not load any sectors now.

Comment: You've omitted the code for `readdisk`, but it presumably makes an int 0x13 call, and one of the parameters is probably number of sectors.  If your code with a loop isn't working, then show us that actual code, as a [mcve].

Comment: `int 13h` with `ah=02` is supposed to take the number of sections in `al`, see http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0607.htm.  Currently you do `mov al, 1` before calling `readdisk`, and that value is preserved through the call of `lbatochs`, so you read 1 sector.  If you want 2 sectors, change it to `mov al, 2`.  Or refactor `readdisk` in some other way.

Comment: I was attempting to read a file from a FAT 12 formatted system. The reason I am reading a single sector at a time is because FAT clusters are not guaranteed to be organised and are occasionally fragmented throughout the disk. I am trying to read a file with multiple sectors.

Answer (score 1):

`int 13h` with `ah=02` is supposed to take the number of sections in `al`, see http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0607.htm.  Currently you do `mov al, 1` before calling `readdisk`, and that value is preserved through the call of `lbatochs`, so you read 1 sector.

If you want 42 sectors, change it to `mov al, 42`.  Or refactor `readdisk` in some other way.

Comment: Note to the OP: when reading more than 1 sector you have to be careful to not cross a 64KiB DMA boundary and some very old BIOSes may not be able to support read across a track boundary (aka Multitrack).

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>   readfat:
>        mov byte dl,[es:bx]
> ```

This instruction makes no sense! There's nothing useful to read (yet) at that spot.

---

> However I can not figure out how to read more than one sector from the file.

The reason is that **your code forgets to actually loop back** to the *readfat* label. Once you've loaded a next clusternumber you need to jump back to the top of the loop instead of immediately far jumping to the *BOOT.BIN* binary.

Note that it will not be enough to just insert the missing `jmp`! Because the necessary `add bx, 512` gets destroyed by the `pop bx` instruction, all the **sectors will arrive on top of each other**.

Because of

> This read disk code likely is not causing the issues as I have loaded many other sectors with this.

I did not investigate that part of your code. See if next rewrite works for you:

```
foundfile:
        mov  ax, [es:di+0x0F]  ; dirFirstCluster
        mov  bx, 0x4000
        mov  es, bx
        xor  bx, bx
READSECTOR:
        push es                ; (1)
        push bx                ; (2)
        push ax                ; (3)
        add  ax, 31
        mov  cx, ax
        mov  al, 1
        call readdisk
        pop  ax                ; (3)
        mov  dx, 3
        mul  dx
        shr  ax, 1
        jnc  short evenclus
oddclus:
        shr  ax, 4
evenclus:
        and  ax, 0x0FFF
        cmp  ax, 0x0FF8
        jae  finishedread

        mov  bx, 0x1000        ; FAT
        mov  es, bx
        mov  bx, ax
        mov  ax, [es:bx]       ; Following cluster number
        pop  bx                ; (2)
        pop  es                ; (1)
        ADD  BX, 512       <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        JMP  READSECTOR    <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

finishedread:
        jmp  0x4000:0000
        jmp  fatalerror
```

Comment: Doesn't appear to work for me. I see the file at the address. It doesn't stop trying to read more.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out how to write the loop by myself.

Here is the code if you want to see it:

```
foundfile:
    mov word ax,[es:di+0x0f]
    push ax ;save file cluster
    ;now to parse the fat
    mov dx,second_boot_segment
    mov es,dx ;second_boot_segment
    xor bx,bx ;offset for es
    xor di,di ;offset for es when reading the fat
    
    read_file_sector:
        pop cx ;get file cluster and put in cx
        add cx,31
        push ax ;save cluster again
        mov byte al,[sects_per_cluster] ;cluster size
        call readdisk
        pop ax ;retrieve cluster
        push es
        
    find_cluster:
        mov cx,3
        xor dx,dx
        mul cx ;multiply cluster number by 3
        shr ax,1 ;divide cluster number by 2
        mov cx,fat_segment
        mov es,cx
        mov di,ax
        mov word ax,[es:di]

        jnc short evenclus
        
        oddclus:
            shr ax,4
            jmp short continue_findcluster
            
        evenclus:
            and ax,0x0fff
            
        continue_findcluster:
            cmp ax,0x0ff0
            jae finishedread
            
            add bx,512
            pop es
            push ax ;save cluster for loop
            jmp short read_file_sector
        
    finishedread:
        jmp second_boot_segment:0000
        jmp fatalerror
```

Comment: The `jmp fatalerror` after another unconditional `jmp` is useless.